# How to correct colours of image texture

Tags: image, color

I'm trying to use satellite imagery as an image texture for a 3D map. For some reason, the lakes are coming out grey. I'm trying to get them to look as close as possible to the source image.

[image: Lakes appear grey in Blender]

In QGIS they are almost black:

[image: Lakes appear more natural in QGIS]

I have tried:

- using RGB colour ramp to adjust the colours. I can change the shade of the grey but nothing more
- using Bright/Contrast. Again, can change the shade a bit but not fix it
- Changing the colour of the illumination (sun) to something more yellow. This one gets the closest but I still can't get it looking like what I see in QGIS.

Any suggestions for what might be causing this/things to try?

Comment: Your material is reflective, this makes the colors look different of course, especially when the environment is just the default grey world as I suspect. Also the water just reflecting the plain grey "sky" back won't help with the appearance. Apart from that, if you didn't change the _Color Management_ settings they are by default set to _View Transform_ > _Filmic_, which already makes the colors seem a bit more washed out, and the _Look_ is "None" by default, you should change that to "Medium High Contrast" or "High Contrast".

Comment: Thank you! That's got it looking much better. I'll still have to play around more to get it right but this is definitely working.

Comment: For the dark lakes: usually water is very mirror-like reflective when viewed from a shallow angle but less reflective when viewed perpendicular to its surface, like most objects (the keyword here is "Fresnel"). So when viewing them from above it's mostly the deep water getting less light which makes them appear dark.